# Why is there a pointer cursor over the whole row in reputation tab table when only the arrow is actually clickable?

Tags: support, design, profile-page, user-interface

I was trying to view what rep I earned in my early days starting with Meta.SE. There was this section (in red box) where Google Chrome said I could click to open but I couldn't. I had to click the arrow sign (in red circle) to be able to open the tab:
[image]

It is weird that I can't click in a place where I could supposedly can click. Why can't I open the tab when pressing the red box area and have to click the small arrow to open? It can be annoying to have to put your mouse just right over that small arrow while Google Chrome says that you can click somewhere else.

Comment: It is really not. I am putting this mainly under [tag:feature-request] while the other OP put it under [tag:bug]

Comment: Yes it is. Essentially, feature request and bug report are the same: they both can be either completed, or rejected. If you would just ask "why is this?" without requesting to fix/change it's a different story and I will reopen.

Comment: @ghosts wrong edit. This is not a feature request. (if it was, it's a dupe)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then why was my edit approved? I still got +2 rep.

Comment: @ghosts mistakes happen. One reviewer did notice the tags and rejected the edit, two others did not pay attention to the tags and approved. You got +2 indeed, no harm done.